# Nested query in SOLR filter query (fq)

Tags: solr

I have the following case.

Solr documents has fields --> id and status. Id is not unique. Unique is the combination of these two elements.
Documents with same id have different statuses.

List of Documents

-ID-  -STATUS-
  id1                1
  id1                2
  id1                3
  id1                4
  id2                1
  id2                2
  id3                1

I need to make query that takes all documents with specific status and to exclude documents that don't have other specific status. 
As an example I need to get all documents with status 2 and don't have status 3. 
The expected result should be document :
     id2            2

Another example: all documents with status 1 and don't have status 3. Then the result should be: 
     id2                1
     id3                1

Here is my query that don't work
(hostPart)/solr/select/?q=status:1&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&fl=id,status&fq=-id:(id:* AND status:2)
The problem is in filter query(fq) part. In fq must be the ids of the documents with status 2 and if the current document id is in this list to be excluded.
I guess some subquery must be used in fq part or something else. 

Just for information I am using APACHE SOLR 3.6 and document count is around 100k.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Interesting qn. Just wondering, if you can't make `status` a multi-valued field?

Comment: Scheme is old and cannot be changed. Changing involves much work. And my boss won't allow me.